# Three doubts in the proof of Hölder's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, expected-value, almost-everywhere, holder-inequality

I quote **Jacod-Protter (2004)**.

> **Theorem (Hölder's inequality)** Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables with $\mathbb{E}\{|X|^p\}<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}\{|Y|^q\}<\infty$, where $p>1$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Then
> $$|\mathbb{E}\{XY\}|\le\mathbb{E}\{|XY|\}\le\mathbb{E}\{|X|^p\}^{\frac{1}{p}}\mathbb{E}\{|Y|^q\}^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
> **Proof** Without loss of generality, we can assume $X\ge0, Y\ge0$ and $\mathbb{E}\{X^p\}>0$, since $\mathbb{E}\{X^p\}=0$ implies $X^p=0$ a.s., and thus $X=0$ a.s. and there is nothing to prove. [...]

---

*Three questions about initial statement of the proof*:

1. Why are we allowed to say that **"Without loss of generality, we can assume $X\ge0, Y\ge0$"**? Why does not such an assumption have an impact on the proof of the theorem?
2. Why **"$\mathbb{E}\{X^p\}=0$ implies $X^p=0$ a.s."**? Couldn't $X^p$ be distributed in a way such that its expectation is $0$, but it is not almost surely equal to $0$ as a random variable?
3. Finally, why **$X^p=0$ a.s. implies $X=0$ a.s.**? Is this a consequence of the fact that $p>1$, hence it cannot be possible that $X^p=X^{-\infty}=0$, hence meaning that in this case $$X^p=0\text{ a.s.}\iff X=0\text{ a.s.?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well, the first inequality is trival and the second inequality only deals with $|XY|=|X|\cdot|Y|$, $|X |$ and $|Y|$, so it's really a statement about $|X|$ and $|Y|$ which *are* positive random variables.
2. No, this cannot be, since $Z:=X^p$ is assumed positive. Indeed, $P(Z\neq 0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(Z\geq \frac{1}{n})$ by continuity of measures and you have that $0=\mathbb{E}Z\geq n P(Z\geq 1/n)$ by Markov's Inequality, so $P(Z\geq \frac{1}{n})=0$ and we get that $P(Z\neq 0)=0$.
3. This is just the fact that $\{X\neq 0\}=\{X^p\neq 0\}$.

Comment: $1.$ So, since in second inequality we're just dealing with $|X|$ and $|Y|$, either if $X$ is negative and $Y$ is negative or $X$ is positive and $Y$ is negative or $X$ is negative and $Y$ is positive or both $X$ and $Y$ are negative, $|X|$ and $|Y|$ will be, by definition, positive random variables, hence no problem at all to assume $X\ge0$ and $Y\ge0$. Correct? 
$$$$
**2.** Why do you say that $Z:=X^p$  is assumed positive before proving something whose starting point is $Z:=X^p$ is assumed to be $0$?
$$$$
**3.** If, for ex., $p=-\infty$, would it still hold that $\{X\ne0\}=\{X^p\ne0\}$?

Comment: 1. I guess 2. Now we've assumed that $X$ is positive. Hence, $Z:= X^p$ is also positive. 3. No. It would not, but $p>1$.

Comment: Pefect as to points $1.$ and $3.$. As to point $2.$, the question is: why starting from "$Z$ is assumed to be positive in the proof" and then showing why "$E{X^p}=0$ implies $X^p=0$ a.s."?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing  I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean to ask. $EZ=0$ only implies $Z=0$ if we a priori know that $Z\geq 0$.

Comment: That was exactly the explanation I was looking for! Your statement is based upon the fact that, if we assume that $Z\ge0$, then $E(Z)=0$ must necessarily imply that $Z=0\text{ a.s.}$, since $E(Z)=0$ cannot be due to negative values of the random variable $Z$ offsetting positive values  of it (since, as already stated, the initial assumption is that $Z\ge0$). Thank you a lot for all your help